# How to get the relative address of a field in a structure dump. [C]

Tags: c, field, dump

We're working on a C program compiled with arm-eabi-gcc under Linux.

We're using a dump of a large structure and we're having problems determining at which adress we should read various fields of our structure (like 50 of them), (memory alignement and padding aren't so predictable to me).

Is there any way to get the memory mapping of the structure produced by a our compiler. An option in gdb? Or any tool helping us find the correspondance between fields and adress in the dump?

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious here, but if you have a variable (let's say `x`) that is declared as a structure instance (or a pointer to the structure), then you should be able to just type `print  x` (or `print *x` if a pointer) in gdb to dump all members.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the adress of what I want to dump. I already have the dump and need the relative adress of all the members.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it with `gdb`. As an example, I'll use this source:

```
struct A {
  int a;
  char b;
  short c;
};

int main() {
  struct A a;
}
```

Loading up the binary in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) print (int)&((struct A*)0)->a
$1 = 0
(gdb) print (int)&((struct A*)0)->b
$2 = 4
(gdb) print (int)&((struct A*)0)->c
$3 = 6
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to do it for a large number of fields, then you may find it handy to use GDB's new python interface (you'll need a recent version of GDB to use it, I'm using 7.4). I've created offsets.py:

```
import gdb

class Offsets(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super (Offsets, self).__init__ ('offsets-of', gdb.COMMAND_DATA)

    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        argv = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
        if len(argv) != 1:
            raise gdb.GdbError('offsets-of takes exactly 1 argument.')

        stype = gdb.lookup_type(argv[0])

        print argv[0], '{'
        for field in stype.fields():
            print '    %s => %d' % (field.name, field.bitpos//8)
        print '}'

Offsets()
```

Then you can add to your .gdbinit:

```
python
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/script/dir')
import offsets
end
```

Then using it in GDB, like:

```
(gdb) offsets-of "struct A"
struct A {
    a => 0
    b => 4
    c => 6
}
```

This script makes a few simplifying assumptions, like that you don't use bitfields, and it doesn't dig into nested structs, but those changes are3 fairly straightforward if you need them.

Comment: I undertand but I'd like to list like the 50 needed fields in there.

Comment: I made a more complete version of this, thanks for the inspiration. [Clicky](https://github.com/Craxic/PyGDBOffsets/blob/master/offsets.py)

Comment: Your `.gdbinit` looks weird. Why not `source /path/to/script/dir/offsets.py`

Comment: @zhangyoufu: Afaik, source is for running other gdb commands.  So, you could put that snippet in some other file and source it, but I don't believe you can directly source the python script.

Comment: @FatalError: This is documented [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-Commands.html). Watch out Python version (2/3) and make sure you are not using gdb-minimal

Comment: @zhangyoufu: Neat, thanks :-).  Not sure if that's new (I haven't played with gdb in a couple years now) or I just missed it, but handy to know.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone reading this years later, maybe following a search engine result: Since gdb 8.1, its builtin `ptype` command has the `/o` flag for this.
It will print offset and size of MyType's members and also "holes" (padding), like:

```
(gdb) ptype /o MyType
/* offset    |  size */  type = class MyType {
/*  0        |     4 */    int foo;
/* XXX  4-byte hole  */
/*  8        |     8 */    void* ptr;
                           /* total size (bytes):  16 */
                         }
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, IMO. So glad I don't have to futz around with `pahole` for this basic info, as I was before. Thanks (:

Answer (score 4):

You can do it from a C program using the standard `offsetof()` macro, defined in `stddef.h`. However I'm not sure this is what you want, since you may be unable to run it (compiling it on the host will likely return wrong offsets).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct A {
  int a;
  char b;
  short c;
};

int main() {
    printf("Offset of b in A is %zu\n", offsetof(struct A, b));
    return 0;
}
```

However, you may be able to employ some hacks to get the offset from a compiled binary without executing it. Maybe assign a static variable the offset value, and find some way of getting its value.

Comment: Use online GCC or online ASM compiler to get the value quick :)

Answer (score -2):

Seems to me you could write a bit of code like this for the required fields

```
struct MyStruct S;
int Offset_of_X=((long)&(S.X))-((long)&S);
```

to calculate the offset in bytes in this compile situation.

This should account for any alignment issues the compiler has.

Comment: But it lacks efficiency for 50 fields or more.

Comment: This does not compile: pointer arithmetics does not allow you to subtract a pointer to S from a pointer to X.